# PHP: Could not connect to host. Howto add external certificate to trusted using OpenSSL?

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, certificate, crt

My college downloaded cert-name.crt file from external host. Now we need to connect to web service platform, obviously using their SSL certificate. We are a bit confused by OpenSSL documentation. Research didn't help either. All we get is 'Could not connect to host' PHP exception. Just to clear things, interface worked perfectly fine over unsecured HTTP. We use pure Soap library. As an act of desperation we also tried to connect with host without verification by disabling verify_peer variable in SoapClient stream context. Please help, we are under pressure.

Answer (score 0):

To get your started:

By default, PHP looks for the CA file on UNIX systems in, make sure it is readable by the PHP invoker (user via cli, Apache user, etc..), and place the `.crt` file here:

```
/etc/pki/CA
```